# Using DISTINCT to get a unique SQL column in an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Hello I am trying to run the following query to select one of each host_id, but filter out the other rows if the host_id is the same. However, even when using distinct, I get all of the rows. Can someone help me understand why that is? How would I be able to change this so that only the host_id is unique? Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT host_id hostid, host.description customer_name, data_template_data.data_source_path file, host.hostname host_name
FROM data_local
JOIN data_template_data ON data_local.id = data_template_data.local_data_id
LEFT JOIN host ON data_local.host_id = host.id
WHERE data_template_data.data_template_id = 41
AND host.disabled=''
AND data_template_data.data_source_path IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregation or window functions.  Possibly the simplest method is:

```
with h as (
      <your query here>
     )
select h.*
from (select h.*,
             row_number() over (partition by host_id order by host(id) as seqnum
      from h
     ) h
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the keyword "with". Is this not usable in phpmyadmin? Also could you explain what that implementation is doing? I am a little confused.

Comment: Actually I think my version of SQL is too old for the CTE implementation. Any other suggestions.

Comment: @rfdev . . . This is standard SQL available in almost all databases.  You have not specified the database you are using in the question.

Comment: phpmyadmin using MySQL, Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: It is saying WITH is unrecognized. I can't find it now but I read somewhere that MySQL didn't support CTE clauses until later. I am searching to find it.